# How does the log zeta function turn into an integral involving J(x)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

After using the Euler Product formula for the Riemann zeta function and taking the log on both sides and expanding using the Taylor series of log, this sum comes out and is fairly well known:

$$\log\zeta(s) = \displaystyle\sum_p\sum_n\frac{1}{n}p^{-ns} = \sum_p\sum_n\frac{1}{n}s\int_{p^n}^\infty x^{-s-1}dx = s\int_0^\infty J(x)x^{-s-1}dx$$

Where

$$J(x) = \displaystyle\sum_n \frac{1}{n}\pi(x^{\frac{1}{n}})$$

Where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function and the sums are carried out for p prime. My question is where the second integral from 0 to inf comes from and how the 2 sums got absorbed into it and somehow the inclusion of the J function.

Comment: Any function $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)$ can also be evaluated as $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\ \theta(x-n)$ and $s \int\limits_0^\infty \theta(x-n) \ x^{-s-1}\, dx=n^{-s}$, so term-wise integration leads to $F(s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f(x) \ x^{-s-1}\, dx=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a(n)\,n^{-s}$. If $f(x)$ corresponds to Riemanns prime-power counting function $J(x)$ (also referred to as $\Pi(x)$), then $F(s)$ corresponds to $\log\zeta(s)$ and the result is valid for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: For the case $f(x)=J(x)$ the coefficient corresponds to $a(1)=0$ and $a(n)=\frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}$ for $n>1$ where $\Lambda(n)$ is the Von Mangoldt function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function), so the Dirichlet series may be evaluated as $\log\zeta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}\,n^{-s}$ which is valid for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I stumbled across something similar but slightly different after going down a rabbit hole of the big pi function. $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s} = s\int_1^\infty (\sum_{n \le x} a_n) x^{-s-1}$ Is what I found and I did some manipulation using the double sum to get $\displaystyle s\int_1^\infty \bigg(\sum_{n}\sum_{p^n\le x}\frac{1}{n}\bigg) x^{-s-1}$ where the double sum is the big pi function. Not sure if this is entirely correct but it seems to work

Comment: The Heaviside step function can be defined as $\theta (x)=\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & x<0 \\
 1 & x\ge0 \\
\end{array}\right.\right)$, so $s \int\limits_0^\infty \theta(x-n) \ x^{-s-1}\, dx=s \int\limits_n^\infty x^{-s-1}\, dx=n^{-s}$.

Comment: Since $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)=0$ for $x<1$, $F(s)$ can be evaluated as $F(s)=s \int\limits_1^\infty f(x)\ x^{-s-1}\, dx$ (the lower integration limit can be changed from $0$ to $1$). But $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log(n)}=0$ for $x<2$, so in this case $\log\zeta(s)$ can be evaluated as $\log\zeta(s)=s \int\limits_2^\infty \Pi(x)\ x^{-s-1}\, dx$ (the lower integration limit can be changed to $2$).

Comment: The double sum $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{k}\sum\limits_{p^k\le x}\frac{1}{k}$ is sometimes written more compactly as $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{p^k\le x}\frac{1}{k}$ where $p$ is a prime and $k$ is a positive integer which is equivalent to $\Pi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=2}^x \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\log n}=\sum\limits_{p^k\le x} \frac{\log(p)}{\log(p^k)}=\sum\limits_{p^k\le x} \frac{1}{k}$ since $\log(p^k)=k\,\log(p)$.

Comment: The Mellin transform of $f(x)$ is defined as $\mathcal{M}_x[f(x)](s)=\int\limits_0^{\infty} f(x)\, x^{s-1} \, dx$, so $\log\zeta(s)$ is $s$ times the Mellin transform of $\Pi(x)$ evaluated at $-s$:  $\log\zeta(s)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[\Pi(x)](-s)=s\, \int\limits_0^{\infty } \Pi(x)\, x^{-s-1} \, dx$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, I thought that there was something related to the mellin transform, but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a consequence of the following general fact:

> **Theorem:** Let $a_n$ be some sequence of complex numbers and
> $$
> A(x)=\sum_{n\le x}a_n.
> $$
> Then
> $$
> F(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}=s\int_1^\infty{A(x)\over x^{s+1}}\mathrm dx.
> $$
> whenever both side converges absolutely at some $s$ on the right half plane.

To prove this, notice that Riemann-Stieltjes integration gives
$$
\sum_{n\le T}{a_n\over n^s}
=\int_{1^-}^T{\mathrm dA(x)\over x^s}
=A(T)T^{-s}+s\int_1^T{A(x)\over x^{s+1}}\mathrm dx.
$$
Since $F(s)$ converges absolutely at $s$, we know for sure that $\sum_{n\le x}|a_n|=o(x^{\Re(s)})$, which indicates that $A(T)=o(T^{\Re(s)})$. Consequently, making $T\to\infty$ gives the desired result.

To answer the question, we just need to notice that when
$$
a_n=
\begin{cases}
1/k & n=p^k, p\text{ prime},\\
0 & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
we have
$$
\sum_{n\le x}a_n=\sum_{k\ge1}\sum_{p\le x^{1/k}}\frac1k=\sum_{k\ge1}{\pi(x^{1/k})\over k}=J(x)
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}=\sum_p\sum_{k\ge1}{1\over kp^{ks}}=\sum_p\log{1\over1-p^{-s}}=\log\zeta(s).
$$

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n\ge1}{a_n\over n^s}$ "converges absolutely at $\Re(s)>0"$?

Comment: @StevenClark I just edited the answer. I was trying to say the series converges absolutely at some complex number $s$ with its real part $>0$.